# Videorate element causes result to only have a single frame, without it the result is choppy

Tags: c, gstreamer

The file output generated by [this pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPXD9.png) only has a single frame.

I tried removing the videorate element, this did fix my problem but it caused the resulting video to be very choppy.

Any ideas on how to possibly resolve this?

Comment: framerate of 120 from the camera? That seems crazy. Why not just try to reduce that rather than using videorate?

Comment: Also, please post your pipeline as text as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.